IC 7300 Antenna Tuner stops working
I've been using my IC 7300 for several years, and the internal antenna tuner has always worked well for any mismatch up to 3:1 - as described in the manual.  After a recent return from a 2 wk vacation, the rig started behaving strangely and I was getting very poor signal reports compared to previously.  After verifying that the output power levels indicated by my Daiwa tuner SWR meter (the tuner is normally out of the circuit unless I switch it in when the SWR is greater than the internal tuner can handle) were very close to their previous levels, and thoroughly checking out the antennas and feed system (SteppIR - still tuning fine without internal tuner, multiple 40m, 60m, 80m dipoles and HF6V vertical - all below 2:1 SWR) without any significant improvement in signal reports, I did a "partial reset" on the rig, and tried to restore operation. My reports on our local 40m LSB net are now back near previous levels, but only after increasing the mic gain to 80% from the former 70% and the compression to "5" from the former "OFF".
Meanwhile, the internal tuner will not tune any antenna, whether the initial SWR is 1.1:1 (which it would not normally react to), between 1.5:1 and 3:1 (which it would normally retune to 1:1) or above 3:1, which it has never attempted to tune. No matter what antenna is connected, it just briefly flashes red and beeps (~0.5s) and then shuts off. If I press the tuner button brieflfy after that, the indicator turns white, but the antenna tuning is not affected.
I've reported these probably separate problems together, in case there may be some commonality that would pinpoint the cause. Since the partial reset did not seem to change the output problem (except for the needed changes in mic gain and compression), and the Tuner problem is now very evident (I didn't check into it earlier, because that didn't seem to be part of the weak signal problem), it appears that there must be some internal hardware issue with the internal tuner.
Would a Full "Factory Reset" maybe fix this, is there an internal setting I can try to change, ... or should I just send it off for repair???
UPDATE: 28 Sept '24 - First, many thanks to "gschro" for the detailed and very helpful troubleshooting suggestions in response to my original query. Since posting that, I've discovered that the problems with my output signal (independent of the antenna and tuner) were due to a failure in the transmit bypass relay in the ANC4+ noise canceller which was in the antenna circuit. Since the relay was not bypassing the ANC when transmitting, all of the transmitted power was going into the ANC circuit and not reaching the antenna. Eventually (probably due to a component failure in the ANC4+ ?) the RF output to the antenna went to zero in mid-transmission, so that even my neighbors, who can normally copy me fine with 0% power into a dummy load, lost my signal completely.  When I removed the ANC4+ from the circuit, my signal went back to normal.
Unfortunately, the IC-7300 internal tuner is still not working. My external Icom AH4 tuner, which I use to tune a backup long wire on 80m and 160m, DOES still work as it did before when I plug it into the IC-7300 and push the tune button. However, with the external tuner disconnected, the internal tuner (as described earlier) just briefly flashes TUNE and then turns off - for all frequencies and SWR loads.
Following the suggestion of "gschro", I eventually did do an SD backup of the settings, followed by a complete factory reboot of the IC-7300. Unfortunately, once I finally got the settings reset for operating Sideband and FT8, the internal antenna tuner still does not work.
Unless someone can suggest another trouble-shooting option, I'll prepare to send the transceiver to ICOM in Seattle for repair. Mahalo (Thanks!) for all your suggestions!

I'm wondering if a lightning surge damaged it while you were away. Was your antenna connected during that period?

I don't have an answer. or some kind of logical troubleshooting procedure. But I do have some ideas on what I would try if this were my IC-7300. Sorry if you actually covered some of this stuff in your post (and I missed it).

Have you ever heard the ATU relays click when you try to tune? I assume you hold the TUNER button down to force a (re)tune. I'm not sure of the effect (if any) of the RF power level when you tune, but I assume it is greater than 0.

Do you have a dummy load you can connect directly to the radio with a short patch cable, and try to tune that, just to eliminate as much external hardware as you can?

Have you tried the IC-7300 SWR page to see what it thinks the SWR is for various ranges of frequency? It would be interesting to try both a frequency range that you believe should have a reasonable but not perfect match, as well as one that should have a horrible match (e.g. no antennas for that range).

Are the signal reports you mention the verbal reports you receive from other operators on SSB? Do they just report low signal strength, or some kind of audio quality issue?

Do you use the standard hand mic for the IC-7300, or something else? Is there any chance something went wrong with the mic (including cords and connectors)?

Is there anything extraneous connected to your radio (e.g. using USB or ACC jacks)? I would disconnect anything not needed for your testing.

There are various AF/IF gain settings in the menu, but I'm only aware of ones for the USB and ACC interfaces (not MIC). But there are the bandwidth and equalizer settings for audio (I have never messed with them). So unless you see an obvious problem, this might be a good reason for the full reset (see below).


I would certainly try the full factory reset before sending it in for repair. What do you have to loose? It would be good to record all of the menu settings before doing that, either on paper or on the SD card. That way if you fix it, you can see what all has changed.
